# Missing "Return value of function might be undefined" if return value is record

Tags: delphi, warnings, record

When I write a function in Delphi 10.2.3 Pro that has a record as return value and I just leave it empty I don't get a W1035 "W1035 Return value of function '%s' might be undefined" warning. Why don't I get a warning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some sample code?

Comment: If the record is a managed record, that is it contains strings, interfaces, dynamic arrays or anonymous methods, then the compiler default initialises it. This suppresses the warning.  I think. Show a [mcve] though so that we can see your record.

Comment: How would you anticipate initializing a plain `record` at all? Unless you have it defined as a record pointer, it's already initialized, as David said. The contents of that record, on the other hand, is a different story. The compiler has no idea what you want to do with the contents.

Comment: @Jerry It's a value type. Initializing the return value means ensuring that each member of the record is initialized.

Comment: @David Right, I mean it's not like you need to explicitly assign a value directly to the record itself. It's already there. As you said, the compiler takes care of it.

Comment: @Jerry Yes it's there, but not initialized. That's the entire point of the post. The compiler should warn that the record's contents may be ill defined. Just as it does for an integer return value.

Comment: @David: I rather think (can't really prove though) that it is because record return values are in reality not return values at all, they are passed as reference parameters. And these don't tend to cause the warning.

Comment: @Jerry: initializing is easy. Can't test this, but I guess `MyRecord := Default(TMyRecordType);` should work. But even "managed" records, if not initialized explicitly, only have the managed fields initialized (the runtime uses the passed RTTI for that). Any integers, floats, pointers, etc. are not initialized.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "They are passed as reference parameters". Apart from when they are unmanaged and fit in registers.

Comment: @David: I forgot to put in the word "most". The docs say: *"For static-array, record, and set results, if the value occupies one byte it is returned in AL; if the value occupies two bytes it is returned in AX; and if the value occupies four bytes it is returned in EAX. Otherwise, the result is returned in an additional var parameter that is passed to the function after the declared parameters."*

Comment: @RudyVelthuis For dcc32. For other compilers the ABI differs. For instance dcc64 returns records of size up to 8 bytes in a register.

Comment: @David: but ISTM that an explanation for the missing warning is that the record in question is passed as reference parameter.

Comment: @David: true. But that is the logical expansion of the rule I quoted. I don't think that the 64 bit part is documented, though.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis All you need to do is put a single `Integer` in a record and observe that even such records can be returned, passed by value in EAX, to see that at least in some versions the compiler doesn't emit the desired warning. In fact you don't even need to do this, you can read the answer below.

Comment: @David: no Delphi here, in my practice. So I could test that later on, at home, but I see the answer too. So it is even suppressed for small records. Then I guess the "when is a record defined?" question becomes more important.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "return value is a hidden var parameter" is probably relevant though. I think that statement is true semantically from the perspective of the front end. Which would explain why there was no warning. Just when you get to back end code gen does the ABI of return value via register kick in, but that, I believe, is after the warnings are dealt with. So I think your original comment is true from the perspective of the front end, even if the back end, following the ABI, does things differently.

Comment: The issue lies in the language design itself: you can directly set fields on `Result` which prevents the compiler to determine if its initialized or not - sure it could check if every field was assigned or for a static array that every slot was explicitly assigned.

Comment: I guess the problem is also that such a check could at most give a warning that some fields *may* be undefined. I don't think that is worth it. And sometimes, you don't want or need all fields to be defined (just like you don't always need all elements of an array to be defined) and then such a warning is annyoing, because you can't get rid of it unless you make some dummy assignments you actually don't need. It makes sense for scalar types (ordinals, floats, pointers), but not so much for composite types.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:"some fields may be undefined" .  Indeed.  And there is the case that the record is a variant record (I mean "variant" in the traditional TP sense).

Comment: @MartynA: you mean "a record with a case part". Indeed, then parts tend to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the warning is also suppressed for unmanaged record. I guess the reason is that it is difficult for the compiler to keep track with the changes of all the fields. Also, if you modify one of the fields of a record, do you consider the whole record as defined or not?

Here is the code to test:

```
{$O-}

type
  TRecordType = record
    a, b: Word;
  end;

function Test: TRecordType;
begin
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  v: TRecordType;
begin
  v := Test;
  ShowMessage(Format('%d, %d', [v.a, v.b]));
end;
```

It does give me random numbers (Not changing if run repeatedly, because the stack is almost the same).

The assembly code for calling:

```
0046CCA9 E8CAFFFFFF       call Test
0046CCAE 8945F8           mov [ebp-$08],eax
```

The assembly code of `Test`:

```
0046CC78 55               push ebp
0046CC79 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
0046CC7B 51               push ecx
0046CC7C 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]   ; eax is the result, not initiated
0046CC7F 59               pop ecx
0046CC80 5D               pop ebp
0046CC81 C3               ret
```

When the size of the record is not 1, 2, 4, the result is passed by reference as a hidden parameter. For example, if `a` and `b` are `integer`, the assembly code for calling become

```
0046CCAA 8D45F4           lea eax,[ebp-$0c]   ; address of V, V is not initiated
0046CCAD E8C6FFFFFF       call Test
```

The assembly code of `Test`:

```
0046CC78 55               push ebp
0046CC79 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
0046CC7B 51               push ecx
0046CC7C 8945FC           mov [ebp-$04],eax
0046CC7F 59               pop ecx
0046CC80 5D               pop ebp
0046CC81 C3               ret
```

So in both case, the result is undefined without warning.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this is clearly a bug in the warning generator of the compiler.

Keep in mention for records the compilers has to check much more than it does for a simple type like integer or real. For example what would you expect here:

```
function Test: TRecordType;
begin
  result.a := 1;
end;
```

Because the record is partly (for b) undefined the compiler should also mention a W1035 here. On the other side what would you expect for the records with variant cases:

```
TRecordType = record
  ID: string;
  case boolean of
    true:
      (a: integer);
    false:
      (b: string);
end;
```

As you can see here it is not possible to determinate if a record is completely initialized or not. At least the Delphi compiler could warn if static fields of a record are unassigned as we see in case the TRecordType is a class.

I recommend to enter this bug in the embarcadero quality reporting side at
https://quality.embarcadero.com 
and reference to this thread on stack overflow.

Comment: I don't. As you yourself said: it is not always possible to determine if a record is fully defined, and what is "fully defined"? Don't post a bug is the specs are not even entirely clear. A warning like "some fileds of XYZ may be undefined" could work, but I don't know if that is worth it.

Comment: I see a lot of technical arguments why it should or shouldn’t return a warning. The way I look at it is that it’s most likely not the intention of the programmer not to set the result explicitly. For that reason alone there should be a warning or at least a hint in my opinion.

Comment: @Luig76: I agree to your opinion. If not at least a partial of the record is assigned (as your initial solution shows) everybody would expect a warning. Of course a serious specification is difficult because of all mentioned arguments but a warning if nothing is assigned to the result would be helpful probably in all cases.